# HTML video tag issue on MS Edge v25 and IE 11 v11.63

Tags: html, video, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I'm having an issue with HTML 5 videos.

I have been using a video player that I built in HTML 5 for about 2 years. Two days ago a co-worker reported to me the player was not working. The player was giving an error *video tag not supported*.

This error usually shows up for IE8 and below. However my co-worker was using IE 11 on Windows 10.

I tried on my computer and the same link worked fine. I noticed we had different IE versions—mine is 11.0, and his is 11.63.

I did some tests with a very simple video tag, and it did not work at all.

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <video id="videoElement" width="100%" height="100%" controls>
            <source src="myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems like IE 11 (v11.2+) does not support video tags.

I checked youtube and they were using a flash video player for IE11 (v11.63). I also tried on Edge and saw the same issue. Edge v20 works but edge v25 does not.

I can't find anything anywhere regarding this issue.

Did anyone have the same issue on IE11 (v11.63) and Edge v25? Am I going crazy or the video tag is "broken"?

Comment: Is there an example online someplace that we can access directly? Also, "video tag not supported" is not a standard error message in Internet Explorer; you must have this string in your player markup, or a related JavaScript utility.

Comment: Hello Sampson thanks for your reply. 
Just to clarify the "video tag not supported" message is actually a custom message that i added in the player it's not from IE. 

i tried the example of w3school and still did not work for the versions i mentioned above, I found out both browsers IE and Edge had an update 14 days ago exactly on the day. This is the only clue connecting both browsers.  

working example - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: Are these machines domain-joined, and managed by a IT team? Or do you see this issue on a personal machine on your personal home network?

Comment: Yes they are. This is the next test i'm going to do. I'm also trying to update an older version (one that works) to a new version to see if the same machine will work or not.

Comment: Dan, I would inquire about any recent policy changes put in place by your Systems Administrator(s). Being that these are domain-joined, it's likely they will understand what, if any, recent changes may impact the situation.